# React Redux Unit Test case

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(IndexResult)". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(IndexResult)".

Getting this error when I try to use mount

const wrapper = mount();

Comment: Show more code [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Create this function:

```
export const wrapIntoReduxProvider = testingContainerComponent => (
    <Provider store={organizationStore({})}>
        {testingContainerComponent}
    </Provider>
);
```

and wrap your component into it

```
const wrapper = mount(wrapIntoReduxProvider(<YourComponent />));
```

Comment: Plus 1 for higher order component solution

Comment: works well but now I'm not able to access the component's state variable. It's null